# SSIS ForEach Loop with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreach, ssis

I'm looking to create a ForEach Loop in SSIS:

Essentially, I have a set of data with ID numbers that must be unique. When I assign the IDs, I have a check that will make sure these IDs don't already exist in a members table. I am using a count(*) of every record that has a match to determine this. If the count is >0, the records in the initial table are removed and re-inserted to assign it a new ID.

What I'd like to do is setup a loop to continue this process until that initial count is 0 (in case re-adding the record gives it an ID that is *also* existing in the members table.

I believe a ForEach Loop with Variable enumerator is the way to go here, but I'm not quite sure how to set this up using a count.

Comment: Looping in SQL is not real efficient. If you want to assign the next ID, why not just select MAX(ID) + 1, and use something like that. SQL would do that super fast!

Comment: Im working with a number "bank" of 600000-900000, and we were told that we would have those numbers to work with. Of course, there are instances where these numbers exist already. So im not sure that MAX +1 would work...But thank you for the input, i'll certainly give it a shot!

Comment: I think you could do this better with a stored procedure instead of a loop in SSIS, but your question isn't completely clear about what you currently have, and what you need to do.   "I have a set of data" could mean a lot of things.

Comment: Recycling the old numbers is not normally a good idea. when if you give out a free number, that was used a long time ago, it could have been used for something else, and the history would be lost on that number.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds more like an SSIS For Loop container, not a For Each Loop.  The For Loop can test an evaluation expression to decide whether to run another iteration of the loop (e.g. `@count != 0`).

Here's the doco on the For Loop container:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139956.aspx

The For Loop also provides for initialization and iteration expressions, but it sounds like you would not need these.  The definition entry for your count variable can initialize it to a non-0 value.